# Best way to watch the contents of a directory in near-real-time?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, cron

I've got a server with an external HDD, I download files to the main disk then transfer them over to the HDD for storage. I mostly do file management over WinSCP, but it's not possible to move files between disks - is there an easy way to setup a service/daemon to watch a directory on my main disk, and if it detects that said directory isn't empty, move the contents to the HDD? I'd probably want to check it maybe every thirty seconds, just unsure if a cron job or another method is the best.

Comment: Related: [Automatically copy incoming files to multiple folders then remove the source files](https://askubuntu.com/a/1443575/968501)

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel - @Raffa has a nice solution, which is the closest to real-time you're going to get.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically copy incoming files to multiple folders then remove the source files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441969/automatically-copy-incoming-files-to-multiple-folders-then-remove-the-source-fil)