rtmp stream continous a folder with files list mp4 , not working
I would like to modify my code to convert a folder with FFMPEG instead of converting a whole list of files, and loop this list:
#!/bin/bash
    
while true;
do
    ffmpeg -re -i /myfolder/10.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -r 30 -s 1280x720 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/output;
    ffmpeg -re -i /myfolder/11.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -r 30 -s 1280x720 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/output;
    ffmpeg -re -i /myfolder/12.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -r 30 -s 1280x720 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/output;
    ffmpeg -re -i /myfolder/13.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -r 30 -s 1280x720 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/output;
done

my code for convert the folder :
#!/bin/bash

while true;
do
    stream1=/myfolder/*.mp4
    ffmpeg -re -i $stream1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -r 30 -s 1280x720 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/output;
done

This code produces an error:
File '/myfolder/11.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]


the error message is your friend

I can see that this file already exists but why does it not work? FFMPEG does not want to load the files as with the code with the list?

Use at your own risk but ffmpeg has a -y  overwrite output files  option. On a side note, for style and readability, I think you might be better doing something like: for in in /myfolder/*.mp4; do ffmpeg $i; done

In your code snippet:
#!/bin/bash

while true;
do

stream1=/myfolder/*.mp4
ffmpeg -re -i $stream1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -r 30 -s 1280x720 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/output;
done

The unquoted $stream1 (in your case) will expand to:
/myfolder/10.mp4 /myfolder/11.mp4 /myfolder/12.mp4 /myfolder/13.mp4

... and your ffmpeg command-line will look like this:
ffmpeg -re -i /myfolder/10.mp4 /myfolder/11.mp4 /myfolder/12.mp4 /myfolder/13.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -r 30 -s 1280x720 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/output

... making /myfolder/11.mp4 the output file for the input one /myfolder/10.mp4 as ffmpeg's option -i expects only one argument as input.
Therefore, ffmpeg asks for confirmation to overwrite the already existing output filename /myfolder/11.mp4:

File '/myfolder/11.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]

... which you don't want to overwrite as this is one of your input filenames and not output.
That's the explanation part ... However, I am not an ffmpeg expert to suggest how you might specify a whole directory's content as input other than what you already know which is looping over the files and providing them one at a time in a shell loop like the one you provided in your question.
If what you want is just to loop over all existing files without the need to specify all the filenames in the script, then you can use something like this:
#!/bin/bash
    
while true
  do
    for f in /myfolder/*.mp4
      do
      ffmpeg -re -i "$f" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -r 30 -s 1280x720 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/output
    done  
done


@AllanTori ... It's not clear why you don't want to use the first loop ... Probably tell us why and you might get more specific suggestions ... You are still using the loop anyway.

@AllanTori Expanding on what Raffa is saying, the outer while loop appears to be downright useless if not harmful, it will make the inner loop keep converting files till eternity... Are you sure you want to do that?

@Raffa Thank you for all your explanation, I now understand why it did not work, your script works very well, one question still, the MP4 comes from an automatic recording of my camera, which it creates mp4 every 5 min, this script will pass on the new MP4s?

@AllanTori You are welcome ... Yes, it will continuously loop over all existing *.mp4 files under the directory /myfolder/ and will repeat infinitely passing all existing files at each repeated run (including newly created files before each consecutive run) ... However, there are better alternatives to a while true; do ... done loop like using inotifywait for example ... See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/a/1201375 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1443575 and probably https://askubuntu.com/a/1417803
